# Can I use Snort to detect multiple VLANs over site to site VPN?

Tags: cloud-computing, snort

I am studying options to check traffic over multiple VLANs using a Snort cloud machine, since the normal Snort installation requires to get local network and local VLAN information. I thought to use physical machine though all offices (but this is not efficient). Is there a way to have a Snort app on Azure or AWS and have them sniffing all our offices? Or is there any recommendation for an alternative if this is not possible?

Comment: Please clarify: you wish to monitor activity from multiple VLANs flowing over a single VPN? My experience is dated, however, I think you'll find you need to mirror the traffic at the router or switch (ie. port mirroring) - if you don't process this traffic locally to the hardware, you'll need to forward it to the processing box on the remote network. In the past I've seen traffic get processed locally to the network hardware, and interesting sessions forwarded on to a concentrated traffic monitoring solution (if you're using a vswitch/ VPN then traffic *will* be local to that virtual device)